# At the very end of my text file I need to replace a , with a ; via php code

Tags: php

I have a text file that is set up to be loaded automatically to the database but when the file is being written it ends the separators with a `,` however it need the very last line to close with a `;` to avoid and SQL upload error. here is what I have

```
('column1' , 'column2' , 'column3'),
('column1' , 'column2' , 'column3'),
('column1' , 'column2' , 'column3'),
```

here is what I need...

```
('column1' , 'column2' , 'column3'),
('column1' , 'column2' , 'column3'),
('column1' , 'column2' , 'column3');
```

The script that writes to this file keeps adding to it, so it will never know when the last line is until it is done with other functions.

So just prior to an automated upload, I need some PHP code to get this file, go to the last line and change the last character from `,` to `;`

Does anyone know how to only change the last `,` to `;`?

Thanks

OK, so now I am feeling rather silly but I can not seem to write the code to open the file, make the changes and then close the file based on your answers, I want to keep it silple so the

$text = substr($actualText, 0, -1);
$text.=';';

Is the way to go. Can someone give me the full code to open crawl_info.txt (which is my file) do the editing above and then close it out?

Thanks so much.

Comment: its a lot smarter to change the code that writes the file

Comment: Write the commas *before* each line, this way you can handle the first line differently. If finished, simply append a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$text = substr($actualText, 0, -1);
$text.=';';
```

This is assuming that the full stop is indeed the LAST character in the file/variable.

Comment: Ok, so basically, just before I pull the file for upload, I need to use some code to open the text file, get contents, then add those 2 lines of code you wrote above, then re-insert all the info back into the file. Then the upload script can be called on. Is that what you are saying? I just wanna make sure I understand the process.

Comment: Fluffen, I tried to give you an up but it says I am too new so I wanted to say thanks here in this comment, maybe someone else can give you an UP click for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If changing the generating code is not possible you could use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php) with a negative length of -1. Then add the ';'.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
$Arr = str_split($text);
//Split the text into array of characters
$NewText = '';
//Define the new text as empty
for($i = 0;$i < $Arr.length;$i++){
//Loop throught each character
if($i == (Arr.length - 1)){
//if it was the last character put a ;
$NewText .= ";";

}else{
//if not add the normal string
$NewText = $Arr[$i];

}
}
```

THis help you in future manipulation but if your goal ius just that you can use Fluffeh answer as it is more simpler.